# Android Recyclerview OnBindViewHolder update ui only when scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I open app the save ImageView is work but when I click save it don't update the save ImageView , it works only when I scroll the recyclerview and scroll back to that position.

I use Room database to update recycler view item if its in favorite list

```
class AdapterHomeMovie(
    private val databaseDao: DatabaseDao,
    private val onClick: (Movie) -> Unit,
    private val onSave: (Movie) -> Unit
) : ListAdapter<Movie, MovieViewHolder>(DiffCallBack) {
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MovieViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = getItem(position)

    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    holder.bind(item, onSave)
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { onClick(item) }

    if (databaseDao.isSaved(item.title)) holder.imgSave.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_yellow)
    else holder.imgSave.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_save_normal)

    holder.imgSave.setOnClickListener {
        scope.launch {
            if (databaseDao.isSaved(item.title)) {
                databaseDao.deleteSaveMovie(item.title)
            } else {
                databaseDao.insertDownloading(
                    SaveMovie(item.title, item.thumbnail, item.id, item.sid, item.rating.toLong(), System.currentTimeMillis())
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MovieViewHolder {
    return MovieViewHolder(ItemMovieBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

companion object{
    val DiffCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movie>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
            return oldItem.title == newItem.title
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

        override fun getChangePayload(oldItem: Movie, newItem: Movie): Any? {
            return super.getChangePayload(oldItem, newItem)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to notify that the item at position has changed when you update data
holder.imgSave.setOnClickListener {

```
scope.launch {
        if (databaseDao.isSaved(item.title)) {
            databaseDao.deleteSaveMovie(item.title)
        } else {
            databaseDao.insertDownloading(
                SaveMovie(item.title, item.thumbnail, item.id, item.sid, item.rating.toLong(), System.currentTimeMillis())
            )
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap your `List` in `LiveData`. Actually Room supports `LiveData` right out of the box.

I your fragment you can do something like:

```
val liveMovieList : LiveData<List<Movie>> = // fetch data from dao

...

liveMovieList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { movies ->
  yourListAdapter.submitList(movies);
});
```

In your Dao, you can return `LiveData` like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * from movie_table")
fun getAllMovies() : LiveData<List<Movie>>
```

To use `LiveData` you need to add following dependencies in app level build gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def arch_version = "2.1.0"

    ...

    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

***Why should you use LiveData***

> - Ensures your UI matches your data state
> - No memory leaks
> - No crashes due to stopped activities
> - No more manual lifecycle handling
> - Always up to date data
> - Proper configuration changes
> - Sharing resources

You can read more at [LiveData Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: I know that but, the List I use in recycler was from firebase not from Room. thanks for answer anyway